# How to create a file relative to Program.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I want to create a file relative to `Program.cs`. This code in case of VSCode works correct:

```
string myFile1 = @".\temp1.txt";
File.Create(myFile1);
string myFile2 = "./temp2.txt";
File.Create(myFile2);
```

but Visual Studio IDE 2022 creates file in:

```
`MyProject\bin\Debug\net6.0`
```

Is there any universal solution?

Comment: You need to define relative.

Comment: @Soleil what do you mean? please write a code

Comment: C# is a compiled language. This means that `Program.cs` does not exist on the computer that executes this code! The location of the *source code* is completely irrelevant while executing the application. What you actually need is to find the location *of the executable*. How to do this is explained in the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the following method anywhere within your project:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices

public static string GetSourceFilePathName( [CallerFilePath] string? callerFilePath = null )
    => callerFilePath ?? "";
```

Then, you can invoke that method from your `Program.cs`, and it will give you `C:\Users\YOU\Documents\Projects\MyProject\Program.cs`.

I suppose you know what to do from there.

Comment: I've found an unversal solution:
`string netDirectoryPath = @$"{Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)}";
string projectDirectoryPath = @$"{netDirectoryPath}\..\..\..";
File.Create(@$"{projectDirectoryPath}\temp.txt");`

Comment: @DeveloperMister Your code is … odd, to say the least. Why are you going up *three levels*? This doesn’t look very universal at all. You write that the duplicate is not applicable here, but I still think it very much is, and that it solves your problem.